# Is any simple way to create method and set its body dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, dynamic, codedom

I have the body of a method stored as a string and I'm looking to create this method dynamically. However, I'm unsure how to assign its body. I've come across a rather complex method using CodeDom, and another using Emit with OpCodes. Is there a simpler way to utilize the existing code from a string variable?

```
string method_body = "return \"Hello, world!\";"; // there is a method body
DynamicMethod dm = new System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod("My_method",
                 typeof(string), new Type[] { }); // some way to create method dynamically
// any way to set body?
string result = (string)dm.Invoke(...); // I need to write result in a variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at these namespaces:

```
System.Reflection;
System.CodeDom.Compiler;
Microsoft.CSharp;
```

This may get you started: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm

Comment: Oh, thanks! There is the ready class for dynamic compilation in the article, which you refers to.
Suffice it to write

  wwScripting lo_script = new wwScripting("CSharp");                
  lo_script.lSaveSourceCode = true;
  lo_script.AddAssembly("mscorlib.dll");

  string result = (string)lo_script.ExecuteCode(method_body, new object[] { .../*params*/...});

It's very convenient way.

Comment: That way will work, but you should use that method only if you absolutely trust whatever input code is there. If some end user (or, perhaps some downloadable content) has the ability to run code, you should be very careful. Just an FYI so it doesn't bite you down the road.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like what you want is the "compiler as a service". That is not in MS .NET 4.0, but may be in a later release. It is already in Mono, though. Until then, the options available are:

- use `CSharpCodeProvider`, but you'll have to load it in as a method (and create a delegate to it) via reflection
- use `CodeDom`
- use `Reflection.Emit`
- use `Expression`

In 4.0, the `Expression` API is far richer than it was in 3.5, allowing most common constructs without the pain of `CodeDom`. But don't discount `Reflection.Emit` - it takes a little while to get your head around `ILGenerator` and using the stack, but it isn't as bad as people tend to think.

As a side-note, don't use `Invoke` from `DynamicMethod` unless you only want to execute it once. The better approach is to use `CreateDelegate`, then store (and re-use) that delegate:

```
var dm = new System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod("My_method",
    typeof(string), null);
var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, world!");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
Func<string> func = (Func<string>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>));
var s = func();
```

Or with the `Expression` API:

```
var lambda =Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(Expression.Constant("Hello, world"));
var func = lambda.Compile();
var s = func();
```

Answer (score 1):

Save this to a .CS file and compile and execute it on the fly.