# Recreate Exception on client side

Tags: c#, json, rest, exception, reflection

I have the exact same problem as in [Recreate an exception that is serialized in a JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795625/recreate-an-exception-that-is-serialized-in-a-json-response), but I have managed to instantiate the correct type of exception:

```
public class ServiceExceptionData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}
...
private static void handleServiceException(ServiceExceptionData serviceException)
{
   // get exception type
   Type t = Type.GetType(serviceException.Type);

   // create exception instance
   var exceptionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

   // set exception read-only properties: Message, StackTrace
   ???
```

I tried a lot of things to set those properties, here are some of them:

- [Can I change a private readonly field in C# using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934930/can-i-change-a-private-readonly-field-in-c-sharp-using-reflection)
- [Changing read only properties with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706389/changing-read-only-properties-with-reflection)
- [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)
- [Is it possible to get a property's private setter through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219261/is-it-possible-to-get-a-propertys-private-setter-through-reflection)
- [Is any simple way to create method and set its body dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987198/is-any-simple-way-to-create-method-and-set-its-body-dynamically-in-c)

but it doesn't work.

The Exception's properties are defined as:

```
public virtual string Message { get; }
public virtual string StackTrace { get; }
```

So is there any way to set them once I have the exception instance (e.g. by getting the property's field and using `SetValueDirect`) or should I give up and create a derived class and override the properties to give them public setters?